# React-router-dom throws two errors when reading the pathname property

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

when I use the routes with react-router-dom 6, I see two different errors:

1. TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'pathname' of ''undefinded' or 'null'
2. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
   and shows me this code from the react-router's file: C:/Users/FAMILIA/Desktop/packages/react-router/index.tsx:281

   ```
    let {
    pathname = "/",
    search = "",
    hash = "",
    state = null,
   ```

what I have tried: installing again react-router-dom, updating the history dependency to the version 5.1.0

this is my code:

```
import { Router, Routes, Route, Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './views/Home.jsx';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

these are the dependencies of the package.json

```
history
"dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "history": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  }
```

Comment: Where are you attempting to read any `pathname` value?

Comment: that is the weird part, that I'm not trying to read any pathname value. Actually what I show from my code is what I have in my app.js file.

Answer (score 3):

Version 6 of `react-router-dom` has some pretty significant breaking changes from previous versions.

It's not common to use the `Router` import from `react-router-dom` though, even in version 4/5, you'd typically import one of `BrowserRouter`, `HashRouter`, or `MemoryRouter` over the lower level `Router`.

The cause of your issue is found [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L280-L286) in source:

> ```
> export function Router({
>   basename: basenameProp = "/",
>   children = null,
>   location: locationProp,
>   navigationType = NavigationType.Pop,
>   navigator,
>   static: staticProp = false
> }: RouterProps): React.ReactElement | null {
>   ...
>
>   let {
>     pathname = "/", // <-- attempt destructure from undefined
>     search = "",
>     hash = "",
>     state = null,
>     key = "default"
>   } = locationProp;
>
>   ...
> ```

Notice here that the `locationProp` is being destructured from. If you are not providing a `location` prop to the `Router` component then this destructuring fails.

Notice in the higher level routers these props are instantiated and passed for you. The history object (`navigation`) *and* `location` props are created and passed for us. We don't need to manage these ourselves.

[BrowserRouter](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L133-L160)

> ```
> export function BrowserRouter({
>   basename,
>   children,
>   window
> }: BrowserRouterProps) {
>   let historyRef = React.useRef<BrowserHistory>();
>   if (historyRef.current == null) {
>     historyRef.current = createBrowserHistory({ window });
>   }
>
>   let history = historyRef.current;
>   let [state, setState] = React.useState({
>     action: history.action,
>     location: history.location
>   });
>
>   React.useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history]);
>
>   return (
>     <Router
>       basename={basename}
>       children={children}
>       location={state.location}
>       navigationType={state.action}
>       navigator={history}
>     />
>   );
> }
> ```

If you prefer to use the `Router` component then you need to create and pass these props yourself.

Example:

```
import { Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router location={history.location} navigator={history}>
      <div>
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-throws-two-errors-when-reading-the-pathname-property]

The alternative, OFC, is to just use one of the higher level routers instead.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Installing a previous version of the `react-router-dom`. I think is a new error, so I think a lot of people will have the same conflict with the last version of react.