# Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, browser-history

I'm wrapping react app in Router with passing createBrowserHistory prop. But getting "property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouterPops"

Here is my index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "../src/utils/history";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Here is my history.tsx

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

I'm using react-router-dom v6.0.2

Comment: [Router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#router) components no longer take a `history` object in v6.x. You should also instead now use one of the higher level routers, i.e. `BrowserRouter`, etc.

Comment: Can you provide link for any article to overcome this problem

Comment: What are you trying to do with "history"? Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69869828/8690857

Comment: I'm using history in axios interceptor to redirect user to login page if he is not logged in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you could implement a bit more of the logic of one of the higher level routers and get the behavior you want with a custom history object.

[BrowserRouter](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L133-L160) implementation for example:

> ```
> export function BrowserRouter({
>   basename,
>   children,
>   window
> }: BrowserRouterProps) {
>   let historyRef = React.useRef<BrowserHistory>();
>   if (historyRef.current == null) {
>     historyRef.current = createBrowserHistory({ window });
>   }
>
>   let history = historyRef.current;
>   let [state, setState] = React.useState({
>     action: history.action,
>     location: history.location
>   });
>
>   React.useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history]);
>
>   return (
>     <Router
>       basename={basename}
>       children={children}
>       location={state.location}
>       navigationType={state.action}
>       navigator={history}
>     />
>   );
> }
> ```

Create a `CustomRouter` that consumes a custom `history` object and manages the state:

```
const CustomRouter = ({ history, ...props }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    action: history.action,
    location: history.location
  });

  useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history]);

  return (
    <Router
      {...props}
      location={state.location}
      navigationType={state.action}
      navigator={history}
    />
  );
};
```

[image: Edit property-history-does-not-exist-on-type-intrinsicattributes]

Answer (score 2):

## **2023 Answer - React Typescript error: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'**

The exact typescript error I got was :

***Type '{ children: Element; history: BrowserHistory; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & BrowserRouterProps'.
Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & BrowserRouterProps'.***

After hours of many research and troubleshooting the solution that resolves the issue is stated below.

****Step 1 - install "history" into you project dependency****

```
npm i history
```

****Step 2 - import Router and createMemoryHistory from the correct sources****

Importing BrowserRouter from "react-router-dom" is outdated, and also is importing {createBrowserHistory} from "history", so we need to import Router and createMemoryHistory as seen below...

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
```

****Step 3 - define history from createMemoryHistory****

```
const history = createMemoryHistory();
```

****Step 4 - pass the history props to your Router****

Finally you pass history={history} and navigator={history}, as seen below...

```
<Router history={history} navigator={history}>
 <React.StrictMode>
  <App />
 </React.StrictMode>
</Router>
```

**Finally your entire "index.tsx" should look like the following...**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorkerRegistration from "./serviceWorkerRegistration";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const history = createMemoryHistory();

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter history={history} navigator={history}>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App />
        </React.StrictMode>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: 
serviceWorkerRegistration.register();

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: 
reportWebVitals();
```